# Linq randomly returns periodic null results

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, .net-3.5

I've got a linq query, which is admittedly pretty large. I can't identify where it is going wrong because it ONLY happens on the remote server and I don't have the access to debug it. But it is basically like this...

This code lists all of the 'folders' that the current member can see. (Folders contain images.)

```
            if (membership == null || membership.Count() == 0)
                membership = new string[] { "Guests" };

            return DataContext.Folders.Where(f => f.Ring.Keys.Any(k => k.Tag.Id == id))
                .Where(i => i.Ring.Keys.Any(t => membership.Contains(t.Tag.Name))).OrderBy(n => n.Date).DefaultIfEmpty();
```

This code lists all of the 'tags' the user can see (tags are contained in rings, which can be hooked onto folders or images)

```
        IQueryable<Models.Tag> tags = null;
        do
        {
            DataContext = new Models.Contexts.DatabaseDataContext();

            tags = null;
            if (membership == null)
                membership = new string[] { "Guests" };

            tags = DataContext.Tags.Where(t => t.Keys.Any(k => k.Ring.Name == category))
                .Where(t => t.Keys.Any(k => k.Ring.Keys.Any(c => membership.Contains(c.Tag.Name)))).OrderBy(o => o.Name);
        }
        while (tags == null || tags.Count() == 0);

        return tags;
```

I enclosed it in a do loop, much to my dismay, to see if it could force it to actually keep calling until it was no longer null. No such luck, It still comes back empty. Again, this EXACT same code works 'sometimes', and 100% of the time on EVERY test back, querying the SAME database. I have even tried different web hosts - all with the same failures once it is live.

membership is a string[] that contains a list of all of the roles the member belongs to.

```
Folder
- Id
- RingId

Ring
- Id
- Name (Nullable)

Tag
- Id
- Name

Key
- Id
- RingId
- TagId

Image
- Id
- FolderId
- RingId
```

This is the basic database structure setup.

Now, this query runs fine on my local machine - in all of my tests, etc. But when I put it live, it just randomly starts returning null **sometimes**. I cannot find a rhyme or a reason to why, it runs fine for a few requests, then it just stops returning the results.

The result set it returns is pretty large. I'd say about 880 items. And the amount of times it is accessed per second is very, very high. I thought at first maybe it was just the stress of how many people were accessing it.

Is there any information I can provide that might help in debugging this? There are a few other queries similar to this one - I have tried, and tried, and tried, and I simply cannot reproduce the results in a debugger. I am getting all sorts of InvalidCastException calls - but there's never any casting. Everything is being returned as IQueryable - The views do not do anything special except take in Guids and pass the Membership data from the ASP.NET Membership Provider - which I've checked for and confirmed that it is working. (Inserted forced data, instead of letting the provider do it - still fails)

I will try to provide any information needed, but I am really getting frustrated - as none of this is making sense to me (why it would be failing).

Thank you very much for your time. (This is all done in .NET 3.5, ASP.NET MVC 1.0, C# ) - the objects were created using LINQ to SQL.

Comment: The datacontext is disposable, is there any reason you're not disposing it by wrapping it's life span in a using statement?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with this practice. Do you suggest wrapping it in that manner? I do not profess to be anything but a beginner.

Comment: Enclosing it in a using statement just gives me a System.ObjectDisposedException. The return is inside of the using statement - I'm not really sure how else to get data out of it, if I am to dispose of the Data Context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really sounds like a load issue.  Put some perf counters on the web server and watch it for usage.

Comment: How would you suggest solving it - if it is a load issue? I'm not running this on a cheap or weak web server. It runs other large scale applications pretty well. But the load is somewhere between 10,000 ~ 25,000 hits an hour.

Comment: If it is load based, then your only solution is going to be scaling out the app so that you have enough web servers to handle the load without hitting the magic boundary.  Beyond that, create a sample app and contact MS support directly to see if they can fix the bug.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I'm not sure if this is your problem but it's too hard to write it back in a comment,

Your data context is disposable, assuming you're using LINQ to SQL.  Therefore while you want to use it you can wrap it in a using statement like so:

```
    do
    {
        using (DataContext = new Models.Contexts.DatabaseDataContext())
        {

            tags = null;
            if (membership == null)
                membership = new string[] { "Guests" };

            tags = DataContext.Tags.Where(t => t.Keys.Any(k => k.Ring.Name == category))
                .Where(t => t.Keys.Any(k => k.Ring.Keys.Any(c => membership.Contains(c.Tag.Name)))).OrderBy(o => o.Name);
        }
    }
```

This way it will dispose your connection after every attempt to use it, otherwise it will remain in memory for some period of time.  Because this period of time is up to the garbage collector, it could be the reason why it works some times and not others.  Try it and let me know if it fixed your problem.

Comment: This doesn't work because the data context is disposed when the view tries to render the data it got from it.

Comment: I've also tried turning off lazy loading, but I get the same problem. Is there any way to access the data retrieved after the DataContext has been disposed of?

Comment: Unlike most types which implement IDisposable, DataContext doesn't really need disposing - at least not in most cases. See http://csharpindepth.com/ViewNote.aspx?NoteID=89

Comment: :( Unfortunately, I am still back to square one with my problem.

Comment: This was helpful, in a way, as it allowed me to learn more about Linq and to evaluate different ways of doing things - but it doesn't solve the problem - additionally disposing isn't helpful because I still need the data in my View.